# combining drupal commerce product display page with checkout page

Tags: commerce

I am trying to find a good way of combining the Drupal Commerce Product Display page with the checkout page. I am trying to eliminate a page, so that the user would choose the product variation and fill in his profile data all on the same page.

I see that there is a hook_commerce_checkout_page_info_alter() which looks like it may be a start, but it would need more thought of how to actually combine these two pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get to checkout pages without products in your cart ( try visiting /checkout with an empty cart). At least, not without extensive hacks.

I'd recommend keeping the catalogue browse / add to cart separate from the checkout process.

If suitable, you can redirect straight to checkout with a Rule after the product is added to the cart, for user detail input and order completion.

Comment: I know that you cant reach the checkout page without something in your cart. I was going to deal with that by programatically adding an item to the cart by a button click on a different page. I would really like to do what I have described, though, as that is what the client would like, an ability to change the item in the cart from the checkout page (through ajax).